# Fuchsia and Transparency

Tags: colors, transparency

> [Fuchsia] is also commonly used to indicate transparency.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsia_(color)

Does anyone know what this quote means? Why would fuchsia be used to indicate transparency as opposed to a checkered  background?

I'm presuming that this is related to computing because of the transparency component (transparent photos don't exist), but if I'm wrong, please feel free to delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In images the colour Fuchsia is used to indicate that a pixel should be transparent when there isn't an alpha component to the pixel. This is because the colour doesn't occur frequently in pictures.

> opposed to a checkered background

That type of background is used as a visual aid in graphic design programs, it is not stored in the image itself.

Comment: By any chance, do you have an example of this?

Comment: No, but if you search for some sprite tutorials (sprites use this technique quite commonly) you should see this.

Comment: In GIF files, the "transparent" color *is* actually stored in the file. Compare this Tweety Bird in your web browser and in Paint: http://www.mywickedspace.com/graphics/glitter/Animals/i53855315_83351.gif

Comment: (It's up to the person or program making the GIF file what color is used as the transparent color. Most GIF search results I found used white, black, or gray as the transparent color. But a bright color like magenta or green or cyan might be used to help spot stray transparent pixels.)